# How can latex and pdflatex be both symbolic links to same executable (pdftex) and not behave the same?

Tags: tex-core, format-files

When I run

```
$ latex my_doc.tex
```

and

```
$ pdflatex my_doc.tex
```

it works, and when I run

```
$ pdftex my_doc.tex
```

it doesn't work.

The thing is I noticed that both `LaTeX` and `pdflatex` commands are symbolic links to the same `pdftex` executable. That is,

```
$ which latex pdflatex pdftex
```

yields

```
/usr/bin/latex
/usr/bin/pdflatex
/usr/bin/pdftex
```

and

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/latex /usr/bin/pdflatex /usr/bin/pdftex
```

yields

```
/usr/bin/latex -> pdftex
/usr/bin/pdflatex -> pdftex
/usr/bin/pdftex
```

So how is it possible that commands being symbolic links to a same executable do not behave in the same way ?

Thanks.

I have `Ubuntu 12.10` with TeXLive-full 2012.20120611-4 installed.

Comment: `pdftex` is a pdf variant of "plain TeX", that's why you get errors compiling your document with it.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: My question is, perhaps, more a 'linux command' thing than a 'TeX engine/format' thing (I don't know). That is, how is it possible that LaTeX knows when I type latex or pdftex at the command prompt, while both commands point at the same executable?

Comment: Thanks karlkoeller for the welcome ! I will have a look at the starter guide shortly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Programs get passed `argv[0]` ie the name by which they are called as well as any explicit following arguments and they can, and do test this and act accordingly. Basically if you make a symbolic link or copy of a web2c tex executable then it acts like `tex &zzz` where `zzz` is the name of the copy or link.

Comment: Sorry, David, can you explain it a bit better?

Comment: @karlkoeller not really, there isn't anything else to say, the operating system passes the name of the program as the 0th argument so a program can act differently depending on its name just as it acts differently depending on its arguments.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. I remembered my dusty programming (C++) skills !

Comment: @karl: `argv` is a parameter of the `main` function (programming level) which stands for *arguments vector* and contains the values of the command line arguments. `argv` is guaranteed to have at least one element, which is the name of the program. `argc` is another parameter which holds the *argument count*, so when `argc > 1`, the program has arguments to be processed. The logic explained by David is: when `tex` runs, it looks for the value on `argv[0]` and act accordingly. It's actually a cool trick. `:)`

Comment: @Paulo Thanks for the explanation. I know what `argv` and `argc` are 'cause I programmed in C, but I didn't know that this is the way in which TeX-related executables are called. The problem is that I don't speak English too much well and sometimes I have difficulties to understand David's words...

Comment: @karl: oopsie I'm sorry for the C explanation. If I knew, I could cut to the important TeX-related part. `:)`

Comment: @karlkoeller sorry:-)

Comment: @Paulo and David: Why would you have to be sorry? It's OK.