# Why are the latex, pdflatex and pdftex binaries identical?

Tags: tex-core

I apologize if this question is somewhat off-topic but I think that this is the best place to find an answer.  This is sort of an oddity that's confused me for years.  When I run `latex -v` I get:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)
kpathsea version 6.2.0
Copyright 2014 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.6.10; using libpng 1.6.10
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with xpdf version 3.03
```

which is the same thing that I see if I run `pdflatex -v`.  Diving a little deeper, I find that:

```
 ls -l /usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/latex
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 Aug 15  2009 /usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/latex -> pdftex*
```

and

```
 ls -l /usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 Aug 15  2009 /usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex -> pdftex*
```

So it seems that `latex` and `pdflatex` are in fact the same.  But obviously they are not.  `latex` produces dvi files and `pdflatex` produces pdf files, just as they are supposed to.  This question was raised before as a "how question":  [How can latex and pdflatex be both symbolic links to same executable (pdftex) and not behave the same?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124421/how-can-latex-and-pdflatex-be-both-symbolic-links-to-same-executable-pdftex-an) to which the answer is `argv[0]`.

But why? Why are the programs packaged in the same binary and with the same versioning data? I don't think I've encountered this kind of approach anywhere else--it just seems so hacky.  Why not maintain separate executables instead of a single executable with an argv switch-case?

Comment: Why do you think its a hack? By having only one real binary, the common code is all in one place and only the format files and output format have to be selected separately.

Comment: It seems like a hack because if `pdflatex` and `latex` were ever to diverge in a meaningful way, maintaining the single `pdftex` binary would become unnecessarily complex.  It would seem more natural to package `latex` and `pdflatex` as scripts wrapping the core `pdftex` binary.  That seems to be how other programs handle similar situations and it makes sense.  It has the added bonus of transparency/customizability for the user. Only if there is an ironclad guarantee that they will never diverge in any substantive way would it make sense to me for them to be tied to the same binary.

Comment: Customizability is the first to come to mind. If the switches for `latex`, `pdflatex` etc are the only option sets that are ever relevant/usable, then you may be right.  But if anyone ever wants to combine options it would be a lot easier if we could see what options the defaults like `latex` actually use.  The commands are basically black boxes for the vast majority of the community. If there are any advantages to non-standard option configurations, we're unfortunately missing out on them because we can't even see what the options are.

Comment: Perhaps one for [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends): looks more like a discussion than something likely to directly impact on the question and answer(s).

Comment: @mmdanziger It seems to me that this is exactly analogous to how other programs work. All the typesetting logic is the same, it is (mainly) the serialization of the output that differs. It is the equivalent of "save as" in a GUI editor, do you expect to see two completely different drawing programs one to save as pdf and one to save as EPS, or just have one drawing program with customisable output?

Comment: This is a *very* common method by the way

Comment: Many minimalist userspace (e.g. busybox, toolbox) packs dozens or hundreds of commands into a single executable, identified only by their link names. Even in some full fledged userspace implementations, families of commands like grep, egrep, fgrep, etc are often implemented as a combined executable. This isn't uncommon.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is no different to asking why two java executables use the same java runtime. plain tex and latex both need a tex engine to execute the code, they differ in which format file (ie a memory dump of definitions) they load. Classically that was specified by a commandline argument `tex &plain` v `tex &latex` but as a convenience web2c implementations can use the program name to default the format. Similarly the output format (dvi or pdf) can be specified on the command line (or using tex syntax within the file) but the program name can be used to default it.

Note it's really not two different executables packaged as one, it is just defaulting the commandline arguments, for example

```
pdflatex '\pdfoutput=0 \input' file
```

or

```
pdflatex --output-format=dvi file
```

use commandline arguments to produce dvi files using pdflatex.

The behaviour is identical to

```
latex file
```

It is just that `--output-format` gets a different default if the command name is `latex`.

Comment: BTW, `cp`, `rm`, `mv` and `ln` [use this same all-in-one-binary approach on MINIX](http://www.minix3.org/manpages/html1/cp.html)