# How to build a LuaTeX binary with debug info?

Tags: luatex, debugging

I would like to build a binary of LuaTeX with debug info, so that it can be run inside a debugger (like gdb) and one can step through the program in terms of the source code. My goal is to debug the LuaTeX executable purely for gaining knowledge of its internals.

I don't understand how formats stuff works, and it seems like it's getting in the way of setting up debugging environment.

Here is what I tried.

- Compiled `luahbtex`. Pretty easy, works right from the repo.
- Changed `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/lualatex` link to point to the compiled `luahbtex`.
- `lualatex mwe.tex` complains it cannot find `texmf.cnf` where `luahbtex` is located. I copied `texmf.cnf` and changed `TEXMFROOT` to `/usr/local/texlive/2021`.
- I ran `fmtutil -user --all`

Still all I can see is

```
$ lualatex mwe.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.0 (TeX Live 2021)
 restricted system commands enabled.

(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

It works if I copy my `luahbtex` to `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux`, but it's not very convenient to change the system wide executable.

Comment: The format file needs to be generated by the same binary that is going to use it later. (The "format" is basically a dump of the internal state of the program.) So you need to use `fmtutil` (or `mktexfmt` specifying `lualatex` I think) such that it uses the same binary. Check which binary it's using when generating the format. Also you can call `luahbtex` with a `--fmt` flag pointing to the format file, and there also seems to be a `--debug-format` flag that I hadn't seen before (not sure what it does).

Comment: Do you *need* all this work to begin with? On my TeX Live 2021, if I ask `lualatex -version` I get `This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.0 (TeX Live 2021)`

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I used fmtutil.

Comment: @egreg I absolutely don't *need* it. I *want* it. Version number is irrelevant.

Comment: @facetus I mean, LuaLaTeX uses `luahbtex` out of the box. No need to compile it again.

Comment: @egreg It doesn't have debug info, and even it had, I would have needed the exact source code it was compiled from. My goal is to debug the LuaTeX executable purely for gaining knowledge of its internals.

Comment: I've edited the question to make this clearer. I might post an answer if I try it later, but what I recall (or have written down) when I did this a couple of years ago is that all you had to do is make sure the binary you built is on (at the front of) the $PATH when you run `fmtutil`. Then `fmtutil` will see your binary before the system-wide binary, and built the appropriate format for it.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: this answer concerns the special case that you only want to compile the one executable `luahbtex`
and also preserve the original one, while not duplicating the other executable/helper scripts,
instead of compiling/installing the whole TeXLive, which is what the asker of *this particular question*
is trying to do (unsuccessfully).

Because this method are **not officially supported by the scripts**, you may expect encountering several
hard-to-understand errors. If all fails, just do the official way and consume a few GBs of additional
hard disk space/wait a few hours.

The official way is roughly

- Download the TeXLive source code
- Read the files named `README.*`, *especially* `README.2building` and `README.3installing` (as mentioned above, you need to download a lot of support files
  separately and *must* install it before using)

---

#### 1. Build the executable `luahbtex`

It's possible to simply download TeXLive source code and run `./Build --debug` inside.

Note: after building, check if the binary have debug symbols first. (for example with `gdb <executable>`).
Last time I tried `/inst/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/luahbtex` does not have debug symbols, `/Work/texk/web2c` does.

Optionally set `TL_MAKE_FLAGS` environment variable. For example `-j5`.

Alternatively, to compile only LuaTeX: (there are two bugs in the current compilation commands that requires fixing.)

Adapting from section "4.6 Build one engine" in `README.2building` file, run:

```bash
set -e # bash: fail on error, just in case

# fix bug 1
mkdir Work

cd Work        
../configure --without-x --disable-shared --disable-all-pkgs \
    --enable-luahbtex --disable-synctex -C CFLAGS=-g CXXFLAGS=-g
make -j5

# fix bug 2 pplib manually
cd libs/pplib
make -j5
cd ../..

cd texk/web2c
make -j5 luahbtex
```

The compilation takes no more than 5 minutes on a 4-core machine, with the configuration part takes much of the time.

- Note: bug 1: `mkdir Work` is missing from README.2building. Need to be added manually.
- Note: bug 2: for some reason compiling only LuaTeX will not compile pplib. So you need to compile pplib manually first.

  Otherwise you get the error message

  ```cpp
  ../../../texk/web2c/luatexdir/luamd5/md5lib.c:197:10: fatal error: utilsha.h: No such file or directory
    197 | #include "utilsha.h"
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  ```

  Also discussed in https://www.mail-archive.com/dev-luatex@ntg.nl/msg04722.html but no solution there.

To build `luahbtex` instead, change all occurrences of `luatex` to `luahbtex`. (and because of another bug, you need to run `make -j5 luahbtex` *again* after it finishes, because for some reason currently it builds `luaharfbuzz` *before* the `harfbuzz` library.) Otherwise you get the error message

```cpp
In file included from ../../../texk/web2c/luatexdir/luaharfbuzz/src/luaharfbuzz/blob.c:1:
../../../texk/web2c/luatexdir/luaharfbuzz/src/luaharfbuzz/luaharfbuzz.h:4:10: fatal error: hb.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <hb.h>
      |          ^~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

(For the difference, it's explained in `man luatex`:

> The luahbtex variant can use the HarfBuzz engine for glyph shaping, instead of LuaTeX's built-in shaper.

)

#### 2. Use the executable

##### 2.1. Copy to global location

This one is the easiest method, but don't blindly copy paste code from the Internet.

```bash
sudo mv -i /usr/bin/luahbtex /usr/bin/luahbtex__backup
sudo cp ./luahbtex /usr/bin/luahbtex
mktexfmt lualatex
```

The executable uses the called file name to determine what to do, so `luahbtex` → `lualatex` makes a difference. (see [Difference between luatex and lualatex binaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214033/difference-between-luatex-and-lualatex-binaries) for more details)

##### 2.2. Copy to global location, but without overriding the default file

(*actually it may be possible to modify user-local `fmtutil.cnf`, but I don't want to figure this one out*)

This is basically a massive hack, it isn't supposed to work like this.

```bash
cp ./luahbtex /usr/bin/luahbtex__debug
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -rs luahbtex__debug  lualatex__debug
```

then you need to edit `fmtutil.cnf` to specify that `lualatex__debug` format file can be generated from `luahbtex__debug`. To do that, execute

```bash
vim $(kpsewhich fmtutil.cnf)
```

add the line

```bash
lualatex__debug luahbtex__debug language.dat,language.dat.lua lualatex.ini
```

You can run `fmtutil -sys --listcfg` to check the edit is successful.

Then you need to do the following.

```bash
cd ~/.texlive/texmf-var/web2c/luahbtex/
ln -rs ../luahbtex__debug/lualatex__debug.fmt .
```

(Reason: by `strace output`, the executable looks for the fmt file in
`~/.texlive/texmf-var/web2c/luahbtex/lualatex__debug.fmt`
while every time it's generated at
`~/.texlive/texmf-var/web2c/luahbtex__debug/lualatex__debug.fmt`.)

Then the executable can be used as `lualatex__debug`.

##### 2.3. Without global modification at all

(does not work!)

**This method is not officially supported** so the information are mostly by trial and error, may break at any time. Also before editing anything, read the comment at the top of the file.

Because of how the scripts detect the location of the executables, it's quite complex/fragile to get things right. (it's not intended to be used this way anyway)

- While you have to use the new `lualatex` executable to generate the format file, you *have to* use the old
  `mktexfmt`, otherwise it will fail with

  ```
  Can't locate mktexlsr.pl in @INC (@INC contains: X/inst/tlpkg X/inst/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive /usr/lib/perl5/5.34/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.34/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.34/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl) at X/mktexfmt line 23.
  BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at X/mktexfmt line 25.
  ```

  (because according to the explanation in https://github.com/conda-forge/texlive-core-feedstock/issues/19#issuecomment-384236207, it's necessary to install some *additional* things to make `mktexfmt` (alias `fmtutil`) work.)
- Without that, with a global TeX Live, it's also possible to use the global `mktexfmt` instead by making sure that one is being used.

  Unlike what [the comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591794/how-to-build-a-luatex-binary-with-debug-info#comment1487060_591794) claims, it's *not sufficient* to set the `$PATH`.

  This is because, when the format file is not found, the following will be done:

  - `luahbtex` will run `mktexfmt lualatex.fmt`,
  - which in turn runs `luahbtex -ini   -jobname=lualatex -progname=lualatex lualatex.ini` in order to make the format file, but `luahbtex` is searched in the folder which contains `kpsewhich` because
    from the file `$(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFROOT)/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm`:

  ```perl
  sub prepend_own_path {
    my $bindir = dirname(Cwd::abs_path(which('kpsewhich')));
    if (win32()) {
      $bindir =~ s!\\!/!g;
      $ENV{'PATH'} = "$bindir;$ENV{PATH}";
    } else {
      $ENV{'PATH'} = "$bindir:$ENV{PATH}";
    }
  }
  ```

  So the *actual* location of `kpsewhich` (its original location if it's a symlink) matters.

  This one I have no idea how to fix. `cp $(which kpsewhich) .`, make a bash script named `kpsewhich` in the current folder that calls the real one,
  `cp /usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf .`,
  `export PATH="$(realpath .):$PATH"`,
  `mktexfmt lualatex`
  all fails.

Comment: Note. I'm definitely not an expert on this.

Comment: Note. Use `-g3` to include macro definition information in the executable.

Comment: By the way if someone know any better method you can post another answer. All the methods that involve putting the executable with a different name have several flaws (because the programs aren't designed to work like that), I've already pointed them out as far as I can see in the answer.