# Why is pdflatex outing itself as pdftex?

Tags: pdftex, latexmk

I'm running `latexmk -pdf` in my GitLab-CI environment to render `*.tex` files into a PDF.

As I checked the outputs I found, that `latexmk` is calling `pdftex` instead of `pdflatex`:

```
Checking out d4c1eceb as testing-latexmk...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ latexmk -pdf $DOCUMENT.tex
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 21 September 2018, version: 4.60.
Rule 'pdflatex': Rules & subrules not known to be previously run:
   pdflatex
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  "Concept-of-Realization.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Concept-of-Realization.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
```

Now I check what `pdflatex` was doing before I switched to `latexmk`:

```
Checking out ffb7336b as v0.1...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ pdflatex $DOCUMENT.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Concept-of-Realization.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
```

To my suprise, both runs call themselfes `pdftex` instead of `pdflatex`.

**Questions:**

- Why is `pdflatex` calling himself `pdftex`?
- Where is the difference?

Comment: `pdftex` is the engine. `pdflatex` is the format.

Comment: latex is written in tex and in that case is using the pdftex tex implementation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a Linux terminal on `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux` directory:

```
$ file pdflatex
pdflatex: symbolic link to pdftex
```

But with `pdftex`:

```
$ file pdftex
pdftex: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32,
BuildID[sha1]=f304a4bff8b70b6e1693666cfe3a966599c1f918, stripped
```

That is, `pdftex` is always the engine, `pdflatex` is only a link to `pdftex`but not load it with the same options. These are the outputs of `pdflatex` and `pdftext`:

```
$ pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
(preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**

$ pdftex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) 
(preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**
```

As you can see, there are different  **preloaded format**, that match with the apparent command name. The same happen if you try with `latex`. [How can latex and pdflatex be both symbolic links to same executable (pdftex) and not behave the same?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124421/how-can-latex-and-pdflatex-be-both-symbolic-links-to-same-executable-pdftex-an) Well, in short, because pdftex will take as format option the name of the symbolic link, whatever it is, so for the link "foo":

```
~ $ ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/pdftex foo 
~ $ ./foo
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
(preloaded format=foo)
restricted \write18 enabled.
**
```

But if you use both commands with the `-ini` option, no format is loaded, and then is exactly the same stuff:

```
$  pdflatex -ini ## (or pdftex -ini) 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (INITEX)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**
```

And of course, you can use `pdftex`(or `pdflatex`) command but load the `pdflatex` (or `pdftex`) format:

```
$ pdftex -fmt  pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
(preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**
```

In summary: `pdflatex` only call to `pdftex -fmt pdflatex`

Comment: Note that your `file` commands will only produce that output if `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is not set - in a POSIX setting you need to do `file -h`

Comment: Interestingly, this is decently common. systemd does the same for `/usr/bin/{shutdown,reboot,poweroff,...}`, symlinking them to `systemctl` and detecting which command was run by examining `argv[0]`. `lualatex/luatex` does the same thing. It's useful for programs that share a large part of the codebase.